# How to charge for a iOS project on function/feature basis or for complete app or hourly basis

Tags: pay-rate, payment-terms, time-tracking

I am an iOS Developer. I have just started the freelancing and this is my first project for the client. My client is from India and me too. My client has given a checklist of features to me that he wants in his app. He asked me to decide the time required to implement for each task and the price of each separately. he want the complete list of separate task and price of each task, now I am little confused as is this the correct way to decide the price or shall I charge for a complete project or an hourly basis.

If I charge him for on feature basis then how would I decide the price, what parameters should I consider? The task include like Facebook, Gmail authentication, user feedback, Facebook and Twitter sharing, and server-side coding (I am handling server side as well), device orientation etc.

Comment: actually i posted this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com they moved here, that's why the duplicate